# Android equivalent events for Navigating and Navigated

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, webview, navigation

I want to know if there are any events equivalent to the Events `Navigated` and `Navigating` which are available for `WebBrowser` in Windows phone development. I want to use the equivalents of these events in android for a `WebView`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at MSDN the Navigating event should be equivalent to [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), the closest to Navigated would be [onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).